# Java Code Sharply Declines in Speed as Time Passes

Tags: java, performance

I have written a relatively simple Java program that takes a folder of images, samples 2000 pixels from each, and separates the color images from the gray-scale ones. The general code I used for each image is (simplified a bit and not necessarily complete but the main pieces are there):

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read([some File]);
int[] pix = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
pix = img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pix, 0, img.getWidth());
//Check 2000 values. If one color pixel is detected, rename the file to a new folder
pix = null;
img = null;
//Repeat for the next image file
```

When I monitor this code for performance, I notice that the speed precipitously drops after approximately 1000 image files are processed (all the images are comparable). In fact, the speed profile essentially shows a ramp up period, a period of peak performance, and then a sudden drop and snail-like performance. Specifically, the program begins by processing about 40 images per second, ramps up to as many as 120 per second, and then when about 1000 total are processed, drops down to 8 or fewer.

As far as I can tell, this program's resource usage should be relatively constant. It only uses 1 thread (omitting the thread I used to monitor performance) and stores a very limited number of integer variables. I even go so far as to include statements showing that pix and img are null after use just in case the garbage collector does not notice.

The program is behaving as though it is storing the BufferedImages in the heap and not releasing them as quickly as it needs to. Indeed, the Windows Task Manager shows that RAM usage is increasing and then peaks (though the timing is not consistent, it peaks sooner than the speed drops). Does anyone have any suggestions about why this throttling is occurring? I appreciate anyone taking the time to read my question and thank you for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19234572/829571

Comment: `pix = img.getRGB(..., pix, ...)` is overwriting the `pix` array with one that's only 4 elements long. Do you mean to do that?

Comment: Which version of `read(...)` are you calling?

Comment: Why did you mention that *"(all the images are comparable)"*? That would only seem relevant if you actually keep them in memory so you *can* compare them, but then why would you be confused about the program running low on memory if you're keeping 1000+ images in memory?

Comment: @Andreas I mean comparable in the sense that they are all similar in size and type so that each image should take approximately the same time to process (regardless of the behind the scenes processes that may be going on that I am not aware of).

Comment: @AndyTurner could you help me understand why pix is being overwritten with one that is only 4 elements long? The method I called returns an array of all the pixels in the image: getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize) --> int[] pixels. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andreas I am calling the static method read(File) from the ImageIO  library.

Comment: @G-Cam because you reassign the return value of `img.getRGB` to it.

Comment: You don't need to set pix and img to null if they're going out of scope. Can you make a testable example? It sounds like all you need to do is create a loop where you keep reading the files, and check if you still get a memory leak. Also, you can decrease your max heap size (-Xmx1000M). If you do not have a memory leak the GC will start sooner, if you do have a memory leak you will get an OutOfMemoryError.